# how to reverse two Characters of string?

Tags: php, laravel, reverse

I want to reverse two characters of string in PHP. For example `50378f` to `8f3750` please help me.

```
$str= User::where('id',$userid)->pluck('card_id');
$num = strrev($number);
echo $num;
```

This function is reversing very good but I want to reverse two characters not one character.

My function is giving me output example: `12345` to `543210` but I want it like 
`103254`.

Comment: Are you looking to munge strings, or do you have an [endian problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) that you don't know how to fix properly?

Comment: Do you mean _shuffle_ instead of _reverse_? Can you please show us a few more example inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: In your first example, you change `123456` to `563412`, then in your second, you change `12345` to `103254`. Why is the first string mutated to swap the first two characters with the last two characters?  Why is the second string merely reversing the order of every two characters? I don't see any consistency in the logic.  Unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$originalString = '23242526';
$arrayWith2CharsPerElement = str_split($originalString, 2);
$arrayWithReversedKeys = array_reverse($arrayWith2CharsPerElement);
$newStringInReverseOrder = implode($arrayWithReversedKeys);

echo $newStringInReverseOrder; //will print 26252423
```

**Edit: changed the approach to work with odd strings**

```
$string = '121314152';
$countDown = strlen($string);
$substrLength = 2;
$reverseString = '';
while ($countDown > 0) {
    $startPosition = $countDown -2;
    if ($countDown == 1) {
        $startPosition = 0;
        $substrLength = 1;
    }
    $reverseString .= substr($string, $startPosition, $substrLength);
    $countDown -= 2;
}

echo $reverseString; //will print 524131211
```

Comment: You are right! I edited the answer to make it work with odd strings

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
function strReverse($string) {
    $newString = "";

    if ((strlen($string) % 2) != 0) $string = "0". $string;

    for($pos = 0; $pos < strlen($string); $pos++) {
        $chr = substr($string, $pos, 1);
        if (($pos % 2) == 0) {
            $tmp = $chr;
        } else {
            $newString .= $chr . $tmp;
            $tmp = "";
        }
    }

    if ($tmp != "") $newString .= $tmp;
    return $newString;
}

echo strReverse('12345'); // result 103254
```

Answer (score 0):

I have rewrite the function, you can define how many length of character you want to reverse by modify $noOfChar.

Example, if you set $noOfChar = 3, 12345 result will be 1004325.

```
function strReverse($string) {
    $newString = "";

    $noOfChar = 2;
    $remain = strlen($string) % $noOfChar;

    $string = str_repeat("0", $remain) . $string;
    $segment = "";
    for($pos = 0; $pos < strlen($string); $pos++) {
        $segment = $segment . substr($string, $pos, 1);

        if ((($pos + 1) % $noOfChar) == 0) {
            $newString .= strrev($segment);
            $segment = "";
        }
    }

    if ($segment != "") $newString .= strrev($segment);
    return $newString;
}

echo strReverse('12345');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function for reverse string by two slot.

```
function reverseByTwoCharacters($string)
{
    $stringReversed = "";
    if (!empty($string)) {
        $stringLength = strlen($string);
        if ($stringLength % 2 == 0) {
            $splittedString = str_split($string, 2);
        } else {
            $splittedString = str_split(substr($string, 1), 2);
            array_unshift($splittedString, $string[0]);
        }
        $reverseString  = array_reverse($splittedString);
        $stringReversed = implode($reverseString);
    }
    return $stringReversed;
}
$string = "1234567890";
echo reverseByTwoCharacters($string);

// Output
9078563412
```